# Supplement Mapbox geocoder results with external geocoder API

Tags: geocoding, mapbox, point-of-interest

I am still learning JS so please bear with me.

I have built a Mapbox GL JS map and would like to supplement Mapbox geocoding results with those from an external geocoding API as many POIs I need are not returned with the standard Mapbox geocoder (such as campsites and national parks).

I have followed the tutorial to supplement results by querying local data here: [Supplement forward geocoding search results from another data source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/forward-geocode-custom-data/)

I have got this to work with local a geojson source however I cant get it to work when querying an external geocoder.  I am testing with [OpenCage](https://opencagedata.com/tutorials/geocode-in-jquery).

My code for the geocoder instance on the map is:

```
// Load geojson source data                
var myjson;
$.getJSON("<github hosted file>", function(json){
  myjson = json;
});    

// Local geocoder function
function forwardGeocoder(query) {

      var matchingFeatures = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < myjson.features.length; i++) {
      var feature = myjson.features[i];
      if (feature.properties.road_name.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
           feature['place_name'] = ' ' + feature.properties.road_name;
           feature['center'] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
           matchingFeatures.push(feature);
          }
       }

    return matchingFeatures;
}

//Add geocoder/search box
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      localGeocoder: forwardGeocoder,
      country: 'au'
});
```

This works fine for local data pulled in from a geojson source (i.e. already loaded in the client side).  When I try to add an external geocoder into the `forwardGeocoder()` function, the query returns the correct geocoded results and I can get them to appear in the console but they dont appear in the standard mapbox geocoder results list.  Code for the external geocoder (using OpenCage to test).

```
function forwardGeocoder(query){
    var matchingFeatures = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/geojson',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
          'key': 'ab6ad6e3ad3043e2aeb897322ab038f0',
          'q': query,
          'pretty': 1
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        statusCode: {
           200: function(response){  // success
                  var listings = response.features;
                  //console.log(listings);
                  for (var i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
                    var feature = listings[i];
                    if (feature.properties.formatted.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                      feature['place_name'] = ' ' + feature.properties.formatted;
                      feature['center'] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
                      matchingFeatures.push(feature);
                    }
                  }
                console.log(matchingFeatures);
                return matchingFeatures;
              },
              402: function(){
                console.log('hit free-trial daily limit');
                console.log('become a customer: https://opencagedata.com/pricing');
              }
            }
          });
        }
```

Console output from this function:

```
0:
center: (2) [145.516244, -37.4666249]
geometry: {coordinates: Array(2), type: "Point"}
place_name: " Aeroplane Track, Toolangi VIC, Australia"
properties:
annotations: {DMS: {…}, MGRS: "55HCU6878852327", Maidenhead: "QF22sm18wa", Mercator: {…}, OSM: {…}, …}
bounds: {northeast: {…}, southwest: {…}}
components: {ISO_3166-1_alpha-2: "AU", ISO_3166-1_alpha-3: "AUS", _type: "road", continent: "Oceania", country: "Australia", …}
confidence: 7
formatted: "Aeroplane Track, Toolangi VIC, Australia"
__proto__: Object
type: "Feature"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I am able to get results of the geocode to appear correctly (in the same format as the local data version) in the console (`console.log(matchingFeatures)`) but the subsequent `return matchingFeatures` doesnt seem to work to add them to the mapbox geocoder results.

Been searching around for days with no luck.  Annoyingly I feel like this is a common problem as the Mapbox geocoder results are lacking in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do won't work since the localGeocoder option to mapbox-gl-geocoder is synchronous, so it can't be used to supplement results from a 3rd party API without https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/issues/157

Your best option is to either write the code to extend mapbox-gl-geocoder to do this, or write your own replacement of mapbox-gl-geocoder which can call two external services.